# Make list from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some raw data like in picture  1

it's possible to make query and show data like this picture 2

I don't know how to make query so that make result in picture number 2, Can some body help me to solve this problem ?

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

Thanks

Comment: No images please, use formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select user, max(case when data='on' then date end )as start,
            max( case when data ='off' then date end) as end
         from t group by user
```

Comment: I try it and just make one list